# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid when inserting data from datagridview to sql database

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

Hello people i'm a newbie programmer of vb.net, so i have this problem so far, i am searching for a related answer but found no luck, so i decided to post my problem.

so here it is.

```vb
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim connstr As String = "server=midtelephone\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"

    cmdconn = New SqlConnection
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmdconn.ConnectionString = sqlstr
    cmd.Connection = cmdconn
    cmdconn.Open()

    Dim period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        'cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no) values" &_
        '" (@period,@VOUCH_AMT,@INDIVIDUAL_AMT,@check_no,@D_MAILED,@DIR_NO)"

        period = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value()
        VOUCH_AMT = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value()
        INDIVIDUAL_AMT = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value()
        check_no = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value()
        D_MAILED = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value()
        DIR_NO = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value()

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no)values" & _
            "('" & period & "','" & VOUCH_AMT & "','" & INDIVIDUAL_AMT & "','" & check_no & "','" & D_MAILED & "', '" & DIR_NO & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Saved")
    Next
    cmdconn.Close()

End Sub
```

i'd like to update my sql database through datagridview.

( that datagridview was called from another sql query  - cmd.CommandText = " select  period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + claimno.ToString + "'"select  period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + claimno.ToString + "'")

now the problem is/are,
the error/s come up when i click the save button.
whenever i click the save button leaving the other columns empty. errors shows up 
"invalidcastexception was unhandled" (on a certain rows that is empty)
-Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

aaaaaand.. another error comes up when inserting different value in each rows.
specially when i want to insert a datetime value. not really familiar with the code.

is there something wrong with my code?
all processes are good(like pulling up the data) except clicking the save button.
or updating my database. thanks in advance. your replies are much appreciated.

Comment: I updated the code again please take a look, it is a bit more lines.  I included the checking of Null/Nothing, DBNull, empty value.

Comment: @jade thank you, all lines proceeded with no errors, but 1 thing is my concern.. the changes i made in the datagridview doesn't update in my sql database when i click the save button. anyways i'll post it in a new question, or u can help me find a solution right here and right now? :O thx in advance

Comment: do you have an underlying datasource in the datagridview?

Comment: actually there is, the datagridview(EBD_billhistory table) was pulled up from a "private Sub loaddgvfrm3()" cmd.CommandText = "select period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + claimno.ToString + "'" Dim dt As New DataTable da = New SqlDataAdapter da.SelectCommand = cmd da.Fill(dt) frmEb.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt cmdconn.Close()

Comment: actually ,that private sub was pulled up from another form.. did i gave you the appropriate information? or u're looking for extensive info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, I also updated the code to avoid SQL injections.
You must check if the value from cell is DBNull and handle it appropriately

```vb
Dim connstr As String = "server=midtelephone\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"

cmdconn = New SqlConnection
cmd = New SqlCommand
cmdconn.ConnectionString = connstr 'sqlstr
cmd.Connection = cmdconn
cmdconn.Open()

Dim period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO As String
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    'cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no) values" &_
    '" (@period,@VOUCH_AMT,@INDIVIDUAL_AMT,@check_no,@D_MAILED,@DIR_NO)"

    With Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i)

        If IsDBNull(.Cells(0).Value()) OrElse .Cells(0).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(0).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
            period = ""
        Else
            period = .Cells(0).Value()
        End If
        If IsDBNull(.Cells(1).Value()) OrElse .Cells(1).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(1).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
            VOUCH_AMT = "0"
        Else
            VOUCH_AMT = .Cells(1).Value()
        End If
        If IsDBNull(.Cells(2).Value()) OrElse .Cells(2).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(2).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
            INDIVIDUAL_AMT = "0"
        Else
            INDIVIDUAL_AMT = .Cells(2).Value()
        End If
        If IsDBNull(.Cells(3).Value()) OrElse .Cells(3).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(3).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
            check_no = ""
        Else
            check_no = .Cells(3).Value()
        End If
        If IsDBNull(.Cells(4).Value()) OrElse .Cells(4).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(4).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
            D_MAILED = ""
        Else
            D_MAILED = .Cells(4).Value()
        End If
        If IsDBNull(.Cells(5).Value()) OrElse .Cells(5).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(5).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
            DIR_NO = ""
        Else
            DIR_NO = .Cells(5).Value()
        End If

        'period = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(0).Value()), "", .Cells(0).Value())
        'VOUCH_AMT = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(1).Value()), "0", IIf(.Cells(1).Value().ToString().Trim() = "", "0", .Cells(1).Value()))
        'INDIVIDUAL_AMT = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(2).Value()), "0", IIf(.Cells(2).Value().ToString().Trim() = "", "0", .Cells(2).Value()))
        'check_no = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(3).Value()), "", .Cells(3).Value())
        'D_MAILED = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(4).Value()), "", .Cells(4).Value())
        'DIR_NO = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(5).Value()), "", .Cells(5).Value())

    End With

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no)values" & _
        "('" & period.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & VOUCH_AMT & "," & INDIVIDUAL_AMT & ",'" & check_no.Replace("'", "''") & "','" & D_MAILED.Replace("'", "''") & "', '" & DIR_NO.Replace("'", "''") & "')"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Saved")
Next
cmdconn.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, it is working! but where should i put the value of my data type? is it like period = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(0).Value()), "", .Cells(0).Value.decimal())

Comment: can you enumerate the data datatype of each columns (period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no) or which columns are expecting number instead of string? Then put either Null value or 0 value instead of ""

Comment: period = char(25)
vouch_amt = decimal(18,2)
individual_Amt = decimal(18,2)
check_no = char(15)
d_mailed = datetime
dir_no = char(15)

Comment: @Newbiematt, There, I've updated the code.  Hope this gives you the right answer.

Comment: thank you! but a new error occured after clicking the save button -missingmemberexception was unhandled "Public member 'Trim' on type 'DBNull' not found"..  :(. how does the trim works anyway? the error was highlighted in this line - VOUCH_AMT = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(1).Value()), "0", IIf(.Cells(1).Value().Trim() = "", "0", .Cells(1).Value()))- when i tried to put a value on its cell

Comment: @Newbiematt, can you replace all .Value().Trim() to .Value().ToString().Trim() that should work fine now.

Comment: thank you for updating the code, all codes works fine by saving. but an error still occurs at the end. (the msgbox prompted 8th times wherein i only edited 1 column and left other columns the way they were (cuz they have default value , some are nulls )) - nullreferenceexception was unhandled "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in my sql table those columns are allowable nulls. so if i leave them empty it will still proceed to updating the database, i'd like to post an image but it seems i need more reputation to do that .. so yeah. thats what i wanna do. :(

Comment: btw the error was highlighted in this line - VOUCH_AMT = IIf(IsDBNull(.Cells(1).Value()), "0", IIf(.Cells(1).Value().ToString().Trim() = "", "0", .Cells(1).Value()))- thanks a bunch for very informative replies. i really appreciate it <3

Comment: hello, i wonder why the msgbox("Saved") loops for like 7th or 8times ?.

Comment: It is because You have 8 records and you loop through it.

Comment: Thank you! now the problem is that my database is not updating the changes that i've made in datagridview? how come its not updating any changes from datagridview when in fact we have cmd.executenonquery()?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to pass values to command as parameters. Check small portion of code below:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no) values" &_
    " (@period,@VOUCH_AMT,@INDIVIDUAL_AMT,@check_no,@D_MAILED,@DIR_NO)"
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@Period", iif(period is dbnull.value, 0, period))
```

Comment: thank you for posting up an answer, the '@ syntax' doesn't work on me though. the answer posted above was more likely functional in my forms, now the problem is, it seems that those values that i inserted in the dgv was not updated in my database.